# "From: not found" when trying to run a Python script in Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker

I have a python script which runs as entrypoint in a Docker container, the problem is that Docker throws an error when it's executed.

```
/app/script.py: from: not found
/app/script.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have added a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python` to my Python script but it hasn't solved the problem.

This is my script.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch
RUN set -ex; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get -y install firefox-esr; \
    apt -y install python-pip; \
    pip install selenium; \
RUN chmod +x /app/script.py
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/script.py"]
```

**NOTE**: This container is being deployed in [id.heroku.com](https://id.heroku.com/)

Comment: It's not finding the module dude, it says ```from: not found```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]; the Dockerfile, how you're launching the container, the first line or two of the script?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/script.py"]` resolve this?

Comment: Also, if memory serves me, a coming Docker release will raise an error with the `\` after `pip install selenium`

Comment: ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/script.py"] solved it. Thanks!